# Truffle wrapper

Tags: truffle, ganache

```
ExampleContract {
    address public miner;
    constructor(){
        address miner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

I am using `truffle` and `ganache-cli` and I executed the following command:

```
truffle migrate --network exampleNetwork
```

After finishing the process, a contract was created. I can see contract address, but I don't know what address is the deployer account and then save to miner variable. Is the address in the ganache pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deployer account is the first account in ganache. This is the default account, unless you explicitly specify from. To access this account in your code, you can use `web3` and do a `console.log` on the client side. For example, use this:

```
const accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
console.log(accounts[0]); 
//This will be by default your deployer account, unless otherwise specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Truffle provides the `truffle networks` command that will show you all your deployed contract instances. This includes address and network information. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't specified your default `from` account in your `truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js` file, truffle will automatically deploy contracts from the first account created by ganache.

When you instantiate a new ganache instance, look for the output and that's where you'll find the generated accounts. If you want deterministic behaviour, always set the same 12-word passphrase by setting the `-m` (or `--mnemonic`) parameter of `ganache-cli`.

Try to also look for the "contract creation" transaction because it will have a "from" property - which is your deployer. [Here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x477369e951659c64259428e65142dbc321fd583c#code)'s an example on Etherscan. Additionally, as @gnidan mentioned, `truffle networks` will show a lot of useful information.

**Warning**: if you use truffle in the console via `truffle develop` or `truffle console`, do make sure to set your `web3.eth.defaultAccount` or otherwise you'll encounter a lot of problems if you forget to set the `from` param.